# JestClient is throwing SocketTimeoutException after being idle for sometime

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, javabeans, elasticsearch-jest

I'm using JEST to connect to elasticsearch in a spring-boot application. When the application is idle (doesn't send any requests to elasticsearch) for some time, then the JestClient is throwing SocketTImeoutException. I'm creating the client using a bean:

```
@Bean
public JestClient client() throws Exception {
    JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
    factory.setHttpClientConfig(new HttpClientConfig
        .Builder(esURL)
        .multiThreaded(true)
        .connTimeout(60000)
        .readTimeout(60000)
        .defaultMaxTotalConnectionPerRoute(10)
        .maxTotalConnection(100).build());
    return factory.getObject();
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: What version of es? and jest?

Comment: ES version 5.6.5 & Jest version 5.3.3

Comment: Have you found a solution already? I have the exact same issue: the first request in a while is then taking 30 seconds and a timeout occurs.. then the next requests give almost instant response back) (using jest 2.0.4)

Comment: @Depzor @pkgajulapalli Just mentioning an idea I would try: look into this feature - https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/pull/149 - meaning, configure `maxConnectionIdleTime` so that the idle connections are killed **before** actually being used (which would result in the timeout exception you get). An example in the tests themselves: https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/v2.0.4/jest/src/test/java/io/searchbox/client/JestClientFactoryIntegrationTest.java#L116

Comment: @andrei-stefan Mmm when adding this: .IllegalStateException: Expected the service to be RUNNING, but the service has FAILED

Comment: Looks weird. That's just a parameter, why would you get that just by adding it?! Are you sure it's the parameter's fault?

Comment: Mmm guava dependency conflict: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;

Comment: Bummer. When I looked in GH that feature should be available in the Jest version you are using.

Comment: @AndreiStefan yes it seems to work now! (was using guava 16.0 and 19.0 is required) and no more time outs occur after being idle for some time. Thanks a lot. What would be a good setting for maxConnectionIdleTime, currently set it to 10 seconds... why 10 and not 1 second for instance?

Comment: I can imagine that you would want to reuse connections and not create one every time.

Comment: And a 1 second idle time would kill them really often.

Answer (score 3):

An idea I would try: look into this feature - https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/pull/149 - meaning, configure `maxConnectionIdleTime` so that the idle connections are killed before actually being used (which would result in the timeout exception you get). An example in the tests themselves: https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/v2.0.4/jest/src/test/java/io/searchbox/client/JestClientFactoryIntegrationTest.java#L116

Regarding the value to use for it, I am not sure what is the timeout for the network socket... guessing 30 seconds. And whatever you set for the `maxConnectionIdleTime` it should be less than that. Maybe try to observe from the timeouts you get what idle time protects you and which not.